# VLC command line to stream/convert/record from an rtsp stream

Tags: streaming, command-line-interface, vlc, transcoding

I am using Lubuntu linux 18.04LTS, VLC 3.0.8  trying to record via vlc a video stream from a security camera and so far have not had success.  I tried using the GUI "Convert" but despite choosing mp4, it seems to only play back as an mp3.  Then I thought the command line might work, but I haven't found a clear tutorial in how to set up the right parameters.  The closest I've gotten is this, which is:

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://@192.168.0.xyz:XXXX/videofeed --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:file{mux=mp4,dst=/media/my/external/hard/disk/yard-01.mp4,no-overwrite}" :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

The problem is the file created is not usable/readable.  Using Gnome MPV player, I get "Format not recognized."  And it doesn't play.  Xine seems to play it, but treat it as a silent audio file (guessing at that).  When I look at the command line messages, I get a long scroll of "mp4 mux warning: i_length <= 0" which, I am guessing, cannot be good.

I'm the first to admit I don't know much about the options in that line above...just cut them from other folks' posts who said they got this to work.  Is there something I can tweak above to make it record video properly?  It doesn't have to be mp4, just something decent that will allow me to get a good feed for security purposes.

I should add that the streaming part works fine in VLC.  I have a nice feed whenever I want via live streaming.  So I know the hardware and access part is fine.  It's just the transcoding that I think is going awry.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!